# how to use ssh to connect vm in namespace?

Tags: cloud, openstack

What I want to do:
use python script to login the vm in openstack environment

What I did so far:

1. I used CLI: `openstack keypair create abc > /root/keydir/abc` to create openstack keypair and use `chmod 600 abc` to change the
   permission
2. Then I create a vm from dashboard and use the key which I created just now
3. I set up the vm and wait it to the right state
4. At last I use this command in controller node:

```
ip netns exec qdhcp-c8db7805-c5e8-aaaa-xxxx-xxxxx ssh -i /root/keydir/abc
root@192.168.111.104(vm's ip) "ping 127.0.0.1 -c 10 "
```

5. When I run this in python, it shows me: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)`.
6. I run the command in Linux directly it prompt me to input password, and this not the result I want

Why doesn't the keypair work?

Comment: Your question needs reformatting! Maybe read the tutorial if unsure how to do it.

Comment: ok thanks , i have changethe format

Comment: You could have tried harder: I edited your question; please review!

Comment: I think it's better you post your question on https://serverfault.com because it's more related to servers/infrastructure than to coding

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the admin account (not "root").  The account name depends on how "cloud-init" is configured on your Linux image, but it is typically:

- "ubuntu" for Ubuntu
- "debian" for Debian
- "ec2-user" for RHEL, Fedora, CentOS, etcetera
- and others.

By default, the "sshd" configs don't (shouldn't!) allow SSH login to the "root" account over the network.